# Is that possible let android device can only instll my apps

Tags: android

I wanna my android tablet only can install my apps, prevent other apps. and also user cannot uninstall these apps.
Means that tablet is only suitable for my customer. Users cannot do extra operations.

Comment: Sounds absolutely terrible. Actually, it sounds malicious. If you have  a legitimate non-malicious purpose for something like this, I would seriously consider explaining the back-story in your question.

Comment: Do you want this on a pristine/stock Android OS version, on an Android version of yours or what?

Answer (score 3):

Build a custom ROM for it, and remove all install functionality.  It's not a built in capability of the OS.